# Scala Ordinal Method Call Aliasing

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apache-spark, implicit

In Spark SQL we have `Row` objects which contain a list of records that make up a row (think `Seq[Any]`). A `Row`has ordinal accessors such as `.getInt(0)` or `getString(2)`.

Say ordinal 0 = ID and ordinal 1 = Name. It becomes hard to remember what ordinal is what, making the code confusing.

Say for example I have the following code

```
def doStuff(row: Row) = {
  //extract some items from the row into a tuple;
  (row.getInt(0), row.getString(1)) //tuple of ID, Name
}
```

The question becomes how could I create aliases for these fields in a Row object?

I was thinking I could create methods which take a implicit Row object;

```
def id(implicit row: Row) = row.getInt(0)
def name(implicit row: Row) = row.getString(1)
```

I could then rewrite the above as;

```
def doStuff(implicit row: Row) = {
  //extract some items from the row into a tuple;
  (id, name) //tuple of ID, Name
}
```

Is there a better/neater approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implicitly add those accessor methods to row:

```
implicit class AppRow(r:Row) extends AnyVal {
    def id:String = r.getInt(0)
    def name:String = r.getString(1)
}
```

Then use it as:

```
def doStuff(row: Row) = {
  val value = (row.id, row.name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to convert `Row` into a domain-specific case class, which IMHO leads to more readable code:

```
case class Employee(id: Int, name: String)

val yourRDD: SchemaRDD = ???
val employees: RDD[Employee] = yourRDD.map { row => 
  Employee(row.getInt(0), row.getString(1))
}

def doStuff(e: Employee) = {
  (e.name, e.id)
}
```